# SOQL - How to access property of the objects in the collection for use in condition?

Tags: apex, soql

I am quite new to SOQL so I don't know if it is even possible this way. I want to have query like this:

```
Account[] childrenAccs;
...
Account[] parentAccs = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :childrenAccs.ParentId];
```

With this query I want to get all Accounts, which have Id equal to ParentId of any Account from childrenAccs collection. Is this possible to achieve somehow? Or I have to extract `ParentId`s from `childrenAccs` and use that in the condition WHERE IN instead?

Thanks a lot for advices

Comment: It's possible, first you need to collect parent ids in a set and do a query on account matching account ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Set or list is used against IN operator.

Try something like this:.

```
// Set to collect parent ids
Set<Id> setParentId = new Set<Id>();

// query on all Child Accounts, added ParentId != null for getting all child records
for(Account objAccount: [SELECT Id, ParentId, Name FROM Account
    WHERE ParentId != null]) {
    setParentId.add(objAccount.ParentId);
}

// Here you can use, ParentId IN :setParentId, in SOQL to get all parents
List<Account> lstParentAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE 
    ParentId IN :setParentId];
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN statement requires a list, and in this case, a list of Ids. You can use apex to gather the ids into a set, and then bind that variable in the query.

```
Account[] childrenAccs;
...
set<Id> ParentIds = new set<Id>();
for (Account a : childrenAccs) ParentIds.add(a.ParentId);
Account[] parentAccs = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :ParentIds];
```